# How to create an adaptable counter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

So I am trying to count the number of times a certain character occurs from a **score (.txt)** file. The file says something like [$$$$$#$$#$$$]

Im trying to create a counter that counts the number of times $ occurs but resets every time a # happens.

This is all I have come up with so far but doesn't account for the restart.

```
with open ("{}".format(score), 'r') as f:
    scoreLines = f.read().splitlines()
    y = str(scoreLines)
    $_count = int(y.count('$'))
```

The count is reflected in another part of the program which is outputting a wave. So every time a # occurs the wave needs to stop and start again. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to keep feeding the count of $ to the wave outputting module every time you see a #?

Comment: @RamkishoreM yes

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use split

```
for sequence in y.split('#'):
    wave_outputting_function(.., len(sequence), ...)
```

(assuming y contains your entire file as a string without linebreaks)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using iterators:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def handle_count(count):
    print("count", count)


def main():
    with open("splitter.txt", "rt") as fhandle:
        for line in (d.strip() for d in fhandle):
            for d in (i.count('$') for i in line.split('#')):
                handle_count(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```